# How do I fix the mongodb inside docker container after `mongo:latest` has changed?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I get this error when I build docker container:

```
upvotocracy-db | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T06:51:26.012+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20573,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Wrong mongod version","attr":{"error":"UPGRADE PROBLEM:
 Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"4.2\" }. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4-compatibility/#feature-compatibility. :: caused by :: Invalid value for featureCompatibilityVersiondocument in a
dmin.system.version, found 4.2, expected '4.4' or '4.9' or '5.0. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 4.4, see the documentation on upgrading at https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4/#upgrade-procedures."}}
```

What can I do to fix? I think `mongo:latest` was just changed and it doesn't support my old db.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
 22   mongo:
 23     env_file: .env
 24     container_name: ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_MONGO_NAME}
 25     restart: always
 26     image: mongo:latest
 27     env_file: .env
 28     volumes:
 29       - ./mongo_data:/data/db
 30     ports:
 31       - "127.0.0.1:${DOCKER_CONTAINER_MONGO_PORT}:27017"
 32     networks:
 33       - ${DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME}
```

Here is another error I get after going from 4.2 to 5.0:

```
unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5
```

Comment: Change `mongo:latest` to `mongo:4.2`. Then do an upgrade in a controlled fashion.

Comment: I changed to mongo:4.2 and i get an exit code 14 which says file type is of 5.x

Comment: If I read the error message correctly, you have featureCompatibilityVersion set to 4.2 in your database. That's only valid for Mongo version 4.4 and 4.2. So if it also says that your database is already (at least partly) version 5 you might be in a weird state.
Maybe it's been upgraded to version 5 and you just need to remove the 4.2 compatibility setting. I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: i think that's the issue just don't know how to change it.

Comment: It must be` mongo:4.4`. 4.2 is too far apart from 5.0

Comment: `unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw: [1626284326:947417][1:0x7ff2983e4b00], connection
: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports vers`

Comment: ok, this one says you cannot downgrade after you had "exit code 14". This is the JIRA ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-14264, it equally apply to downgrade from 5 to 4.4.  I could reproduce the first part - I started v4.4, set featureCompatibility to 4.2, upgraded to v5.0 and got the original error in the question. Mongo exited with  code 62 and docker restarted it because of `restart: always`. When I stopped it with `docker-compose down` downgraded to 4.4 it started with no problems.  It actually worked even if I downgraded to 4.2. Did you have anything valuable in ./mongo_data ?

Comment: I hired someone to fix. They copied the `./mongo_data` directory over to a fresh docker with 5.0 and did the upgrade properly. Then we copied the `./mongo_data` directory back to production.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when I started docker using different versions.
Delete the volume using

> docker volume rm <volume_id>

and then restart.

Comment: For me it's a bind mount that I have to delete and restart.